# USING two webpages to submit form values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I have a total of 3 pages; form elements are distributed among two pages, "eg1.html" and "eg2.html", but the form elements are submitted to "eg.php".

Here is the **code for eg.php**:

```
$size=$_POST["fontsize"];
$label=$_POST["label"];
$age=$_POST["age"];
$sex =$_POST["sex"];
```

**code for eg1.html**

```
 <html> 
 <body> 
 <form action="eg.php" method="post"> 
 <input type="radio" name="fontsize" value="3"/> 
 <link to eg2.html>
 <input type="radio" name="label" value="stacks"/> 
 <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down"> 
 </form> 
 </body>
```

**code for eg2.html**

```
 <html> 
 <body> 
 <form action="eg.php" method="post">
 <input type="radio" name="age" value="18"/> 
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/> 
 <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down"> 
 </form> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

I have added a link to `eg2.html` in `eg1.html`. That means that first the user will open `eg1.html`; he will select the form elements before submitting the form elements he will be provided with a link to `eg2.html`; once he clicks on the link, he will be redirected to eg2.html.

In `eg2.html` he should be able to select other form elements, and after selecting he will be redirected back to `eg1.html`, where he will be able to submit all form elements to `eg.php` [which includes both eg1 and eg2]

I have seen many websites using this tecniques.

Comment: Huh? Please explain this better. It sounds like your user is partially filling out forms, submitting them, then going back to complete them. Is that correct?

Comment: Also please check your spelling; it's hard enough to decipher your sentences as is

Comment: Yes AS i have mentioned form elements are distributed among two pages eg1.html and eg2.html ...please check there is <link to eg2.html> in eg1.html that means user  has not submited the form he should click on link which will redirect him to eg2.html there he  will select and  submits the values which will be taken by eg.php and then he will be redirected back to eg1.html to submit other values in eg.php...

Comment: Can you possibly split that into, you know, multiple sentences? Train of thought typing is awfully hard to understand. Maybe even try a diagram?

Comment: There is a core rule with forms on the web: always send a form to itself, validate it there AND THEN redirect if necessary.

Comment: 1. Why do you need 2 forms? This can be done with one, you could show/hide the second form for example. If you have to keep track of the two forms, you could use sessions. But i would say, create a second div and place the second part of the form inside that div. create a show/hide function or a toggle function, that switches between form part 1 and form part2. But only use one form.

Comment: You really need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: hello busy people can you explain to me with an example or with sample code????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle this, you can

1. Let the server cache the first half of the response
2. Pass the data along to the second page to be submitted together
3. Put them in 1 page, and make it look like 2 pages

To cache on the server, you'll probably need to use temp files or a database. This is very cumbersome, but the upside is that the user can do half of it, go for dinner, and come back to continue.

To pass the data along to the second page, you can choose to attach that information in the link provided to the next page, using `location.hash`. Alternatively, you can use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

The third one is also relatively easy to accomplish. Use `divs` or `iframes` for each page and have the top document hold the data.